# Oracle APEX form on table, don't reset table pagination after changing values through the form

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a form on top of a report, and when the user updates values in the report, the form pops up, they make edits, and then click "Apply Changes". There are many rows in the report and right now I have pagination set per every 15 pages. The report is set to enable partial refreshes so the data updates right after the user clicks "Apply Changes". However, if I am on any page other than the first page of the report, it resets the pagination and brings me back to the first page. Is there a way to update the report but stay on the page I'm making the edit for? That way the user can immediately see the change they made through the form.

Comment: I'm glad you solved the problem. While not ideal, another option would be to take the values from the form page and map them into the DOM of the parent/report page with JavaScript. This would eliminate the round trip to the server and fix the pagination issue. But if what you have is good enough, then it's probably better left alone - at least until you upgrade APEX. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue by using a Dialog Closed dynamic action executing the following javascript:

`window.location.reload(false);`

It refreshes the browser after the user makes edits, and the pagination does not reset. This is a workaround because the Refresh dynamic action resets pagination. Again this is in APEX 5.1.3.

Comment: Worked also in version 20.2! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Which Apex version do you use? I've just tried it on apex.oracle.com which runs Apex 20 and - no problem at all. Once I edit some value in a form, branch returns me to interactive report, to exactly the same page which I left.

Check branch's **Behavior** - it is set to *redirect to page or URL*, target is page where the interactive report is; check other properties for the **target**. Its **action** should be set to "None" (offered are: clear regions, reset regions, **reset pagination** which might be set in your branch properties).

Comment: Littlefoot unfortunately I am on 5.1.3....I have the "Reset Pagination" option set to No on my page target. For some reason the pagination still updates once the page submits. I have some processes (UPDATE and some custom PL/SQL) running after clicking the Apply Changes button, but nothing to do with pagination. Not sure what's going on here!

Comment: I see ... unfortunately, I wouldn't know what might be wrong, and I don't have Apex 5 any more. Hopefully, someone else will be able to assist.